# Spring RestTemplate for fetching bytes

Tags: java, spring, cxf, spring-rest

I am fetching the byte array using Spring Framework `RestTemplate`.
But I also need to fetch the *media type* of the fetched result.

The *media type* of this byte array can be of any type.

The code used now for fetching bytes is below.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf")));

ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = restTemp.exchange(
       url,
       HttpMethod.GET,
       entity,
       byte[].class,
       documentId
);
```

The above code will fetch only PDF content type.

So I have the following questions:

- How to set the content type to accept any generic *media type* because the service at the other end is providing any random *media type* for the byte array?
- Could someone please suggest how the *media type* can be fetched?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 21):

Just not send the `accept` header to not force the server to return that `content-type`. This is the same as sending a wildcard `*/*`

```
//HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.WILDCARD));
ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = restTemp.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class,documentId);
```

After this, extract the `content-type` from the headers of the response

```
 byte body[] = result.getBody();
 MediaType contentType = result.getHeaders().getContentType();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `MediaType` as  `application/octet-stream` , look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783921/which-mime-type-to-use-for-a-binary-file-thats-specific-to-my-program)

Answer (score 0):

You can store a media type in the HTTP headers and use - ResponseEntity.getHeaders(), for instance. or you can wrap byte array and media type into holder class.

Comment: Thanks for the Response. Yes this will give me MediaType but only the one set in acceptHeader.. But the bytearray can be anything like a pdf or jpg or png or txt file ..

Answer (score 0):

MediaType mediaType = result.getHeaders().getContentType();

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the Response. Yes this will give me MediaType but only the one set in acceptHeader.. But the bytearray can be anything like a pdf or jpg or png or txt file ..

Comment: It's not the one set in the accept header, it's set by the server when it creates the response. If the server sets the MediaType based on what the byte array represents (e.g. application/pdf for a pdf file), then you can use the Content-Type header as such.