# Mp3 download link: "download" attribute simply doesn't work

Tags: html, download

Adding a `download` attribute to my mp3 link (`<a href='file.mp3' download>link</a>`) is supposed to ensure that the mp3 gets *downloaded* as opposed to *played*, but it doesn't work. Also tried `download=true` and `download=file.mp3` to no avail

Was that attribute disabled or something? What's the alternative now?

Comment: It's not supported in all browsers yet; http://caniuse.com/#feat=download. What browser are you using?

Comment: I got the same behaviour on Firefox, Chrome, IE and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by m.lanser in his comment, not every browser supports it.
The best way to have a browser to download a file is to set its mime type to `application/octet-stream`, as noted also in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6783972/2477547)

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/octet-stream">, is that correct? So far it doesn't help.

Comment: you have to set it server side in the http header, you can have a, let' say, php page that set the mime type for the mp3 you want to have downloaded.
Here is some more explanations: http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/