# what should be the common mime type for .rpm , '.swi' and '.swix' ?

Tags: spring, rest, browser, mime-types

As I'm using Spring /Rest, my service should have annotation with @produces .. i don't know the mime type for .rpm , '.swix' ,'.swi' for my browser download these files.

Comment: What are .swi and .swix types?

Comment: they are software file stored in the server for the switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'd suggest you send data in the binary format for that you can use `application/octet-stream`. Look at very closely [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6783972/2265497).

Comment: Thanks.It works fine for '.swi' and '.swix' correct file is downloaded. But it doesn't work for'.rpm' file. After downloading the .rpm , junk data only downloaded .Can you please suggest a solution.

Comment: Can you please tell me., Can we download a '.rpm' file using 'servletoutputstream' like the same way to download the other files? or we need any conversion ..?

Comment: "After downloading the .rpm , junk data only downloaded" - explain please, what does it mean

Comment: I suppose we can. It should work for any kind of files because it transports row bytes

Comment: yeah it's working fine when hitting request 'url' . but it doesn't supported by swagger .thanks a lot . Code wise working fine .