# How to encode binary data with Indy Mime?

Tags: delphi, encoding, mime, indy, delphi-xe7

I have an Ansi string that I use to store binary data - bytes in 0-255 range (I know it should be a Byte array or so, but it is not much difference between them).
I want to pass this "binary string" through Indy MIME (TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString / TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString) and obtain a human-readable **ANSI** string.

I thought that the output of Encode/DecodeString will be a string that has only ANSI characters in it if I use IndyTextEncoding_8Bit encoding. But I was wrong!

so, how to encode binary data with Indy Mime (something similar to [application/octet-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783921/which-mime-type-to-use-for-a-binary-file-thats-specific-to-my-program))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DONT use `AnsiString` for binary data!

`AnsiString` is not an appropriate container for binary data, especially in a Unicode environment like XE7. Use a *proper* byte container, like `T(Id)Bytes` or `TMemoryStream` instead.

You can't pass `AnsiString` *as-is* through the `TId(Encoder|Decoder)MIME` string methods, only `UnicodeString`, so implicit RTL Ansi<->Unicode conversions are likely to corrupt your binary data. Use the binary-oriented methods instead (`(Encode|Decode)Bytes()`, `(Encode|Decode)Stream()`). They exist for a reason.

That being said, Indy 10 does have a `TIdMemoryBufferStream` class (desktop platforms only), so if you MUST use `AnsiString` (and you really shouldn't), you can wrap it in a `TStream` interface without having to make additional copies of data in memory.  For example:

```
var
  Binary: AnsiString;
  Strm: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
  Base64: String;
begin
  Binary := ...; // binary data
  Strm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(PAnsiChar(Binary), Length(Binary));
  try
    Base64 := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(Strm);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
  // use Base64 as needed...
end;
```

```
var
  Base64: String;
  Strm: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
  Binary: AnsiString;
begin
  Base64 := ...; // encoded data
  SetLength(Binary, (Length(Base64) div 4) * 3);
  Strm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(PAnsiChar(Binary), Length(Binary));
  try
    TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Base64, Strm);
    SetLength(Binary, Strm.Size);
    SetCodePage(PRawByteString(@Binary)^, 28591, False);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
  // use Binary as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I converted my code to use TIDBytes. It works. One question though: Why AnsiString should not be used to store binary data? AnsiString is nothing more (well.... almost "nothing more") than an array of bytes. As long as you don't convert it to string everything should be fine.

Comment: @mutex `AnsiString` is more than just an array of bytes. It also has an associated codepage, and that is what can cause loss/corruption of binary data when passing `AnsiString` values around carelessly, like you were about to do when passing an `AnsiString` to `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString()`. Also, if you ever need to migrate your code to mobile, `AnsiString` is not available (without a 3rd party patch)